# Rails application and locating a stack trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, stack

I am investigating some performance issue in my Ruby on Rails application. NewRelic is showing me a lot of a particular object having its updated_at attribute updated many times. I'm not entirely sure where this is happening. I decided one way to try to locate this manifestation would be to create an observer for my model and grab a stack trace whenever that attribute gets modified. So I have something like:

```
class FooObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def before_save(foo)

    if foo.updated_at_changed?
      Rails.logger.info("Foo changed - print stack trace??")
    end
  end

end
```

What's the best way to get this stack trace at this point? Or the caller?

Any advice would be great. I need to stop having this update happen over and over, it's hurting performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [caller](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_m_kernel.html#Kernel.caller)

```
Rails.logger.info caller
```

Comment: thats new! :) the default behavior for this case (at least as I have witnessed it) is: post the same answer, and make dozens of edits in quick succession until the new answer is looking better :D